# MDX Query Join Two Dimensions

Tags: sql, mdx, olap, olap-cube, adomd.net

I have an MDX query as follows:

```
WITH
    MEMBER [MatCode] AS [Product].[Material]

SELECT
([MatCode]) on 0,
([Activity].[ActivityCode].[T-50051151]) ON 1 
FROM
[Cube]
```

This returns a value such as:

```
            MatCode
T-50051151  Null
```

Which tells me it is not joining the activity code to the description when I know they match up

How can I correct my MDX query to join activity code to material?

thanks

Comment: What do you want to see? What the MDX that you show does deliver in the cell that you show as `Null` is the value of the default measure of your cube at coordinates `[Product].[Material].[All]` and `([Activity].[ActivityCode].[T-50051151]`.

Comment: @FrankPl I would like to see the material code for the specified activity code, I am very new to this sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try something like the following to look for areas of the cube with data? You'll can use the `WHERE` clause to slice by a specific measure in your cube.

```
SELECT
    {[Activity].[ActivityCode].[T-50051151]} ON 0,
//NON EMPTY //<<include to hide nulls
    {[Product].[Material].members} on 1 
FROM
    [Cube]
WHERE
    ([Measures].[someMeasure])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns the _ default _ value / cell for the tuple :

```
( [Activity].[ActivityCode].[T-50051151], [Product].[Material].defaultMember )
```

as well as the .defaultMember for every other dimension not mentionned in your query. There is nothing wrong with it.